# Reactjs Cannot Update During an Existing State Transition

Tags: reactjs, jwt, react-router-dom

I'm creating a global function that checks whether the `jwt token` is expired or not.

I call this function if I'm fetching data from the `api` to confirm the user but I'm getting the error that I `cannot update during an existing state transition` and I don't have a clue what it means.

I also notice the the `if(Date.now() >= expiredTime)` was the one whose causing the problem

```
const AuthConfig = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))["token"];

  if (token) {
    let { exp } = jwt_decode(token);
    let expiredTime = exp * 1000 - 60000;

    if (Date.now() >= expiredTime) {
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      history.push("/login");
    } else {
      return {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      };
    }
  }
};
```

I'm not sure if its correct but I call the function like this, since if `jwt token` is `expired` it redirect to the `login` page.

```
const config = AuthConfig()
const productData = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/product", config);
  setProduct(data);
};
```

I updated this peace of code and I could login to the application but when the `jwt expires` and it redirect to `login` using `history.push` I till get the same `error`. I tried using `Redirect` but its a little slow and I could still navigate in `privateroutes` before redirecting me to `login`

```
// old
let expiredTime = exp * 1000 - 60000;    
if (Date.now() >= expiredTime)

// change
if (exp < Date.now() / 1000)
```

Comment: show how you are calling this function.

Comment: All this code is in the render loop of this component. When you call the history.push it probably re renders your component and calls history.push again, and so on infinitely.

Comment: I updated my answer @windowsill what do you propose to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would start from the beginning telling you that if this is a project that is going to production you always must put the auth token check in the backend especially if we talk about jwt authentication.
Otherwise if you have the strict necessity to put it in the React component i would suggest you to handle this with Promises doing something like this:

```js
const config = Promise.all(AuthConfig()).then(()=> productData());
```

I would even consider to change the productData function to check if the data variable is not null before saving the state that is the reason why the compiler is giving you that error.

```js
  const productData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/product", config);
    data && setProduct(data);
  };
```

Finally consider putting this in the backend. Open another question if you need help on the backend too, i'll be glad to help you.
Have a nice day!

Comment: I can't throw a `json expired` message but I'll explore flask more. Could you explain why should I use a promise? I want to understand it more

Comment: You should use the promise because in this way you are sure that the user jwt is checked before running the function that gets data that you should be protecting. 
To make it more cohesive you can even check the response from the Promise setting a return value in the "then" argument.
Just one last thing, if you think that the answer is appropriate can you give an upvote or even mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how your code is used within a component context.

Currently your API and `setProduct` are called regardless whether `AuthConfig()` returns any value.  During this time, you are also calling history.push(), which may be the reason why you encountered the error.

I can recommend you to check config for value before you try to call the API.

```
const config = AuthConfig()

if (config) {
  const productData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/product", config);
    setProduct(data);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that AuthConfig is a hook, since it contains a hook. And that it's consumed in a React component.

Raise the responsibility of redirecting to the consumer and try to express your logic as effects of their dependencies.

```
const useAuthConfig = ({ onExpire }) => {
  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))["token"];

  const [isExpired, setIsExpired] = useState(!token);

  // Only callback once, when the expired flag turns on
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isExpired) onExpire();
  }, [isExpired]);

  // Check the token every render
  // This doesn't really make sense cause the expired state
  // will only update when the parent happens to update (which
  // is arbitrary) but w/e
  if (token) {
    let { exp } = jwt_decode(token);
    let expiredTime = exp * 1000 - 60000;

    if (Date.now() >= expiredTime) {
      setIsExpired(true);
      return null;
    }
  }

  // Don't make a new reference to this object every time
  const header = useMemo(() => !isExpired
  ? ({
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
  : null, [isExpired, token]);

  return header;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  // Let the caller decide what to do on expiry,
  // and let useAuthConfig just worry about the auth config
  const config = useAuthConfig({
    onExpire: () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      history.push("/login");
    }
  });

  const productData = async (config) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/product", config);
    setProduct(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (config) {
      productData(config);
    }
  }, [config]);
};
```